# Remove "generated by doxygen" and timestamp in PDF

Tags: doxygen

As the title. I've just started using doxygen, with the first test run I noticed the PDF created has "created by doxygen 1.8.3.1" followed by the date and time, across the front page.

Is it possible to remove this? or even just move it, say to the end of the document?

I have noted other similar questions but only for the HTML (or RTF which Im not generating) and not PDF

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by using a custom LaTeX header.

First generate a default one using

```
doxygen -w latex header.tex footer.tex doxygen.sty
```

now edit the header.tex and look for the "Generated on ..." part and replace that by something of your liking.

Then mention the customized header in doxygen's configuration file

```
LATEX_HEADER           = header.tex
```

and run doxygen as normal.

**Note**: When you upgrade to a newer version of doxygen you may need to update your custom header as well.

Comment: this does work, however other dynamic parts of the file (project name, datetime) then cease to function... (maybe I should find some time to read more documentation :)

Comment: OK after some searching in the doxygen.org documentation I found `$date` and `$projectname`   http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/config.html#cfg_latex_header

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the update part! Just updated and latex make failed - figure it's for this! :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use the [`HTML_FOOTER`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_html_footer) configuration tag.

I haven't tested this, but it sounds right:

> The HTML_FOOTER tag can be used to specify a user-defined HTML footer for each generated HTML page. If the tag is left blank doxygen will generate a standard footer.

Comment: This seems to change the footer in the HTML output alright but had no effect on the *PDF* output.